# Incorrect count in output

Tags: python

I made a simple guessing game for practice. The program is functioning without an error but the output given is a wrong value.

Here is the code:

```
import random

welcome_phrase = "Hi there. What's your name?"
print("{:s}".format(welcome_phrase))

user_name = input("Name: ")
print("Hey {:s}, I am Crash. Let's play a game. I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20. Can you guess the number?".format(user_name))

attempts = 5
secret_num = random.randint(1,20)

for attempt in range (attempts):
    guess = int(input("Guess the number: "))
    if guess > secret_num:
        print("Your guess is higher than the number. Try again")
    elif guess < secret_num:
        print("Your guess is lower than the number. Try again.")
    else:
        print("Well done! {:d} is the right number.".format(guess))
        print("It took you {:d} attempts.".format(attempt))
        break

if guess != secret_num:
    print("Sorry, you have used up all your chances.")
    print("The number was {:d}".format(secret_num))
```

And here is the output:

[image: This is what the console prints back.]

As you can see in the image above, even though it is clear that 3 attempts were made to guess the right number, Python only counted 2 attempts. Will anyone please let me know how to solve this?

Comment: Copy and paste the console output here please. Also note that Python is a **0-index** language, so attempts 0, 1 & 2 are 3 attempts in total

Comment: `range` starts at 0.

Comment: It will be better to use while loop and break statement in such cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change

```
for attempt in range (attempts):
```

to

```
for attempt in range (1,attempts+1):
```

to solve this, as range starts from 0.